# Windows Server 2008 R2 Email internal domains

Tags: php, windows, email, internal

I'm currently using a windows 2008 server with IIS, running PHP as a fastCGI module (don't ask me why lol). Anyhow, the issue is, when using the mail function through php, I can send emails to absolutely any email address EXCEPT to a domain which is also configured on the same server. eg I can send auto emails to example@hotmail.com fine, but not to site@mydomain.com. I'm using parallels plesk with 1and1 hosters.

Does anyone know what I am supposed to do to get around this? I have heard the word relay thrown about loosely, but with my limited knowledge of server administration, I'd rather be sure of what to do

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) in your internal DNS so that IIS SMTP knows where to send them.